# Restrict access to shared folder

Tags: asp.net

I have a shared folder called "reports". In this folder there are pdf files.

fd6.pdf
fd3.pdf

After a user "fd3" gets authenticated, the user can access any pdf within this folder via url. Is there a simple way to prevent this?

Comment: Is asp.net running with integrated security? Or do you use forms auth/custom stuff? Did you try removing the read permissions of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like protecting files with the local attribute in web.config

```
 <location path="pdfs/files">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="superuser,admin,VolunteerCoordinator,presenter,ReferralMaker"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

then make sure you have your roles defined to prevent access to the directory you are protecting

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to accomplish this. I'm making the assumption that your authentication is Forms Auth or some other such custom application authentication, and not managed via impersonation (if you are using Windows Auth/impersonation, then you can solve this using ACLs on the files directly).

1. You need to configure IIS so that it will invoke managed modules for PDF files. If you are using IIS7+, this is simple, as you can just use the Integrated Pipeline. If you are using IIS6, or must use the Classic Pipeline, then you'll need to use a [wildcard mapping](http://ruslany.net/2008/09/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-7-integrated-pipeline/), or at least map PDF extensions, to allow managed code to execute for your static content.
2. Create either a separate `IHttpModule`, or add to your web application's Global.asax.cs. What you want to do is attach to the application's `AuthorizeRequest` event.
3. Check the path and file name to see if it matches your rules. If it fails, set the Response.StatusCode to 403 (HTTP: Forbidden).

Global.asax.cs example:

```
protected void Application_AuthorizationRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var application = (HttpApplication)sender;
    var context = application.Context;

    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
        && Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(context.Request.Path)).Equals("reports", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        && Path.GetExtension(context.Request.Path).EndsWith("pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(context.Request.Path);

        if (!context.User.Identity.Name.Equals(fileName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            context.Response.StatusDescription = "You are forbidden to view this file.";
        }
    }
}
```